# Upgraded spring boot 4.20.1,getting error in problems tab for spring boot type category

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sts

After upgrading spring boot 4.20.1, in my application iam getting new error type in the problem tab.
My previous version 4.19 i did not get any error in the problem console.
in my repository getting error ie
`public interface TestInfoRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TestInfo, Integer>{}`
Error:Expected Domain ID type is 'java.lang.Long'
(note: in TestInfo i have declared id is long)
Showing error in multiple files, but in runtime i did not get any error, application works fine.

How can i ignore this error?
[Error in problem tab in sts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZASOk.png)

Comment: [Refer this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1139)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info `TestInfo` uses an `@ID` of `Long`.  The identifier type declared for the repository is `Integer` and mismatched, the reason for the error according to a validation [change in STS](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/457) (which you may be using based on tags).